# Execute an external JavaScript function from a function in another PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I am new to php, Please give me a help if anyone know how to execute an external JavaScript function from a function in another PHP file. (or using Ajax).

In my code (see the comment):

In index.php->

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnUnityReady()

{

u.getUnity().SendMessage("test", "SubmitInputValue", "name");  
}
</script>
```

In chatApp.php ->

```
<?php

 class pfcCommand
 {

function write($chan, $nick, $cmd, $param)
  {

    $data .= $nick."\t";
    $data .= $cmd."\t";
    $data .= $param;

    .
    .

    $this->setMeta("channelid-to-msg", $this->encode($chan), $msgid, $data);

   //FROM HERE, I NEED TO EXECUTE OnUnityReady() FUNCTION in index.html 
   //IN EVERY TIME WHEN EXECUTE THIS write FUNCTION


return $msgid;

}
}
?>
```

Comment: How do you call the write method?

Comment: PHP runs exclusively on the server, and just renders something (usually an HTML page) that's sent to the client. Any JavaScript code it contains is then executed by the client. You do understand this, right?

Comment: You don't execute javascript functions from PHP.  You call PHP pages from javascript via AJAX. You've got it backwards.

Comment: You can request a PHP script with parameters (like `index.php?method=getWhatever&arg=test`) and in the index.php file you can send something back to the browser based on that parameter like `<?php if ($_GET['method'] == 'getWhatever') { echo getWhatever($_GET['arg']); } ?>`. Or `<?php call_user_func($_GET['method'], array($_GET['arg'])); ?>` (for experienced coders).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute a javascript function from within a php script. Especially since javascript is parsed by your browser, using **file_get_contents()** or **cURL** wouldn't work. Find a way to replicate the JavaScript function in PHP :/